# writing a line with input from different rows in python

Tags: python, loops, csv, row

I am trying to write out a line to a new file based on input from a csv file, with elements from different rows and different columns for example

test.csv:

```
name1, value1, integer1, integer1a
name2, value2, integer2, integer2a
name3, value3, integer3, integer3a
```

desired output:

```
command integer1:integer1a moretext integer2:integer2a
command integer2:integer2a moretext integer3:integer3a
```

I realize this will probably some type of loop, I am just getting lost in the references for loop interation and python maps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm sorry, but I find it very hard to figure out what you are asking here. It would help if you included some code to show what you have tried, it'll make it much easier for us to help you. Perhaps you could also take a look at http://whathaveyoutried.com for a great article on how to ask good questions?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest to adapt to your need would be to build a list of tuples from your file :

```
data = []
for l in open('file.csv'):
   data.append( l.strip().split() )
```

at this point data is a list of quadruples. So you can do your example like this:

```
for i in range(len(data)/2):
    _,_,i1,i2 = data[2*i]
    _,_,j1,j2 = data[2*i+1]
    print('command {}:{} moretext {}:{}'.format( i1,i2,j1,j2 ))
```

Here I use _ to say that I don't care about the two first variables of the quadruple. Hence, I don't even named them. It's a nice feature to write clear code.

You can also do this in a single loop:

```
f = open('file.csv')
while True:
   l1 = f.readline()
   l2 = f.readline()
   if not l1 or not l2: break # file ended
   _,_,i1,i2 = l1.strip().split()
   _,_,j1,j2 = l2.strip().split()
   print('command {}:{} moretext {}:{}'.format( i1,i2,j1,j2 ))
```

Comment: Why not combine this into single loop? What if the input file contains  billions of rows? :)

Comment: Because I didn't knew exactly what he wanted. This way is easier to understand when you start.

Comment: I am new to python, what are you referencing with the "_,_"

Comment: I'm sorry for not clarifying, the csv file will have 2 to maybe 100 lines.

Comment: OT here, but I wanted to say that I agree with you about call-by-value vs any other name for calling discipline.

Comment: @deufeufeu you could start with combined loop anyway. By asking you those question I intended to point out that you are reading the file and converting it into the datastructuresc at once, thus resulting in possible huge memory consumption for large files.

Comment: @J0HN I just added the combined loop at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming python 2, you want the output in a text file, and you have the command and moretext saved as variables earlier in the code.

```
from csv import reader

f = reader(open('test.csv'))
data = [str(r[2]) +':' + str(r[3]) for r in f]

out = open('out.txt', 'w') 
for i in range(len(data)-1):
    print >> out, command + data[i] + moretext + data[i+1]
out.close()
```

Comment: It's giving me an error when I get to the line with open. I'm using python 2.7.1 on MacOS

Comment: I just made some edits, can you try again?  Do you have test.csv save in the current working directory?  Also, make sure that you have some test saved under command and moretext.

Comment: It's giving me an error, apparently out.close() needs to be on a non indented line?

Comment: That works, thank you very much! Issue with out.close() was on my side, the way you have it works, thanks again.

Comment: Yes,  You only want to close a file when you are completely done with it.  If it is in the loop it will close prematurely and you will get an error on the next iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple and general function that takes any iterable and generates all sequential pairs (e.g., `1, 2, 3` becomes `(1, 2), (2, 3)`):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    it = iter(iterable)
    a = next(it)
    for b in it:
        yield a, b
        a = b
```

This can then be used to solve your particular problem as follows:

```
with open('outputfile', 'w') as out:
    for (_, _, a1, a2), (_, _, b1, b2) in pairwise(
            [w.strip() for w in l.split(',')] for l in open('test.csv')):
        out.write('command %s:%s moretext %s:%s\n' % (a1, a2, b1, b2))
```

One advantage of doing it this way is that you don't read the whole input into memory before starting the output, thus it will work well for streaming and arbitrarily large files.